# LIBGDX MoveToAction.setPosition() to negative coordinates to move actor out of stage

Tags: java, android, libgdx

In libgdx I want to move actor out of stage using `movetoaction.setposition()` but even when i set`X` coodinate to negative integer it still stops at `x0`.
Here is snipet:

```
move = new MoveToAction();

move.setPosition(-10, e[i].getY());

move.setDuration(5);

e[i].addAction(move);

stage.addActor(e[i]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did a simulation of your code, and it works well, maybe you have another piece of code that modifies its behavior in another time

```
    Button botonTest = new Button(new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("skin/uiskin.json")));
    botonTest.setPosition(50f, 50f);

    MoveToAction move = new MoveToAction();

    move.setPosition(-10f, 50f);
    move.setDuration(5f);

    botonTest.addAction(move);
```

Comment: the class which i used just extends actor class so: Actor1[] e; e = new Actor1[20]; can this cause a problem? as I see you used Button. I'm newby.

Comment: @Khusrav I use the button because I did not know that what actor used your, but I knew it was an actor who admitted of actiones and that could be put on a stage, just use it to test your code like I said, I'm glad it will solve

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, maybe it was because of texture size but when i set it to

```
move.setPosition(-100, e[i].getY());
```

it started working.